# How to access root document when using a firestore trigger (onUpdate) in my cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a trigger for the following documents using wildcards:

```
firestore.document('venue/{venue}/messages/{message}').onUpdate
```

I need to access fields in the root document {`venue`}

Is is possible to do this with cloud functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use the [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) object, as follows:

```
exports.updateWhatever = functions.firestore
    .document('venue/{venue}/messages/{message}')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

        const venueDocID = context.params.venue;
        const venueDocRef = admin.firestore().doc(`venue/${venueDocID}`); 

        const venueDocSnapshot = await venueDocRef.get();
        const foo = venueDocSnapshot.get('foo');
        // ...
        
        // Or
        const venueDataObj = venueDocSnapshot.data();
    });
```